# Refer to section containing a labeled subsection

Tags: hyperref

**Main question:** Is there a way to produce the title of a section containing a labeled subsection? I.e. Consider a document containing the sections `\section{A}\subsection{1}\label{1}`. Using the hyperref package, `\nameref*{1}` outputs "1". Is there some way to define a `\supernameref*{1}` that outputs "A" without specifically referring to a label of the section?

---

**Motivation:** Suppose I have a LaTeXed document which serves as a record for personal correspondence by having sections named by the sender, and subsections referring to particular correspondence. Using custom commands, each section is automatically labeled by its number, and then for usability an additional static label may be added. A small example (sans custom commands) of the sort of document is as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Letters}
\section{John Doe}\label{1.1}
\subsection{Dec. 1, 2015}\label{1.1.1} \label{JD1}
Hello. Goodbye.
\section{Jane Doe}\label{1.2}
\subsection{Dec. 2, 2015}\label{1.2.1} \label{JD2}
Goodbye. Hello.
\chapter{Notes}
In \nameref*{1.1.1}, John says hello before goodbye. However, in \nameref*{1.2.1},
Jane does the opposite!
\end{document}
```

This will output in the Notes chapter:

> In Dec. 1, 2015, John says hello before goodbye. However, in Dec. 2, 2015, Jane does the opposite!

What I want is to define a custom command "\letterref" so that

```
\letterref{1.1.1}
```

outputs

> (John Doe: Dec. 1, 2015)

Obviously, I could just refer to 1.1 directly, but I feel like I should be able to make it happen automatically.
The solution I would like is to define the command by `(\supernameref{#1}:\nameref*{#1})`, but that is predicated on defining a `\supernameref` function.

---

**Attempted solution:** One approach that I considered would work with the automatic labeling. Namely, suppose I wish to reference letter X labeled by L (e.g. JD1 in the example). Then one solution would be to use L to get the subsection number SS (e.g. 1.1.1), truncate the ending substring '.d' to get the section number S (e.g. 1.1), and then use `\nameref*{S}` to get the name (e.g. `\nameref*{1.1}`='John Doe'). However, I am not very TeX-literate and I don't know how to implement this without TeX automatically expanding arguments to commands.  I have worked out (using refcount and xstring packages) how to get a hold of S:

```
\newcommand{\parse}[1]{\StrCount{#1}{.}[\dotnum] \StrBefore[\dotnum]{#1}{.}}
\expandafter\parse{\number\getrefnumber{JD1}}
```

yields 1.1, but then I have no idea how to get \nameref* to wait until 1.1 has been worked out before trying to evaluate.